# How to show QR Code in Custom field

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-field, richtextarea, image-formula, qr-code

I created a QR Code Using LWC. It works well when I show the QR Code on an HTML page.
Now I want to show that QR code which is generated via LWC in a custom field (It can be formula or Rich text area)
How to achieve this.

LWC JS Code:-

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import qrcode from './qrcode.js'; 
import getDetails from '@salesforce/apex/qrCodeGeneratorController.getDetails';

 

export default class QrCodeGenerator extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    dataRetrived = false;
    eventdata;
    renderedCallback() {
            getDetails({recordId : this.recordId})
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);
                    this.eventdata = result;
                    console.log('dr', this.eventdata);
                    this.dataRetrived = true;
                    let strData = JSON.stringify('Name: ' + result.Full_Name__c + ', Email: ' + result.Preferred_Email__c);
                    const qrCodeGenerated = new qrcode(0, 'H');
                    qrCodeGenerated.addData(strData);
                    qrCodeGenerated.make();
                    let element = this.template.querySelector(".qrcode");
                    element.innerHTML = qrCodeGenerated.createSvgTag({});
                })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}
```

qrcode.js (I referred to this to create a QR Code) :
https://github.com/shivanirathi21/LWC-QRCode/blob/master/qrcode.js

when I logged the QR code, I got this value in this format:-

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 106 106"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" x="0" y="0"/><rect width="2" height="2" x="8" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="10" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="12" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="14" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="16" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="18" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="20" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="26" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="28" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="30" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="32" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="34" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="36" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /><rect width="2" height="2" x="40" y="8" fill="black" shape-rendering="crispEdges"  /></svg>
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.